# Regex for limit paragraphs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

The question is asked multiple times, but the snippets I found didnt work well. I have less experience with regex so I hope you can help me.

I want to get paragraphs by limit.
I know I am able to limit my results by preg_match_all.

I have two struggles:

- Paragraphs are "created" by html editor, so attributes are attached sometimes
- If it is possible, i want the `<p>` too, but only get the text is good too

For example:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p attribute="value">Paragraph 2</p>
```

When I limit on one, I want only the first paragraph, but limit 2 should return paragraph 2 too, even it contains attributes.

What I tried:

```
function GetParagraph($content, $limitParagraph = 1)
{
    preg_match_all('~(<p>(.+?)</p>){' . (int)$limitParagraph. '}~i', $sHTML, $aMatches);
    return $aMatches[0];
}
```

Also regex with `'~(<p(.*?)>(.+?)</p>){' . (int)$limitParagraph. '}~i'` didn't work well

Comment: You should consider reading **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)** before comitting too much resources into regex-based HTML parsers.

Comment: I am aware of it, but make it a little bit more simple to return me the two paragraphs without the tags :-)

Comment: This is called parsing. Don't use Regular Expressions for parsing HTML documents. Use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need and should not use Regular Expressions for this kind of task. This is called HTML parsing and should be done using right tools, parsers. In PHP `DOMDocument` along with `DOMXPath` would be your choices:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($paragraphs as $i => $p) {
    // Two paragraphs only
    if ($i >= 2) break;
    echo $dom->saveHTML($p);
}
```

#### Why your RegEx doesn't work?

Because of four reasons:

1. It doesn't include newlines after each `</p>`
2. Variable that holds html content is wrong. (`$sHTML` instead of `$content`)
3. It's not anchored to start traversing from beginning of input string only.
4. `<p>` doesn't match `<p attribute="value">` or some thing other than itself.

Again, this is not recommended but to answer this specifically, below regex should solve these issues:

```
'~^.*?(?:<p[^>]*>.+?</p>\s*){' . $limitParagraph . '}~i'
```

Comment: Your explaination is clear, $sHTML is wrong copy. Further your solution(s) point me to the right direction. Thx!